# Desktop PC restarts continuously after shutdown

Tags: windows-10, bios, motherboard, shutdown, cmos

My win10 desktop pc runs fine, when I can get to the OS.  When I shut down the pc, it immediately restarts, and I'm assuming fails POST, because the nothing appears on screen.  Then it shuts off and restarts again, continuing this ~10 second loop until I pull the power cord.
If I pull out the cmos battery, wait 5 min then replace, I can get one normal power up, and get to BIOS and the OS.  The next time I shut down the PC, it goes back to the restart cycle.  I tried replacing the battery with a new one, as it was a few years old.

I've tried re-seating the ram sticks, all 8gb appear to be functioning correctly.
And I've tried unchecking "automatic restart" on system failure under advanced Startup & Recovery system options.  No change.

Can someone please help me figure out why I cannot shut down my PC correctly?  Right now, I can only power on my pc if I take out the cmos battery, wait 5 min, and reinsert.

My processor is :
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q9550  @ 2.83GHz

Motherboard :
Intel DQ45CB Motherboard E30148-207

Comment: “I've tried re-seating the ram sticks, all 8gb appear to be functioning correctly.” - This was your only test of the memory? Did you run MemTestx86 or equivalent software?

Comment: No, I just looked thru task manager, as it displays the total installed ram.  You're right I should thoroughly test the ram.  I've been focused on the BIOS and cmos battery.

Comment: If you pull the powercord, does it turn on *immediately* once you plug it in? Also, anything tasty in event viewer?

Comment: Yes, as soon as the pc gets power again, it starts up on it's own, and enters the restart loop.  I'm not seeing anything in event viewer that stands out to me (I'm also not too familiar with it).  Nothing about Bios, cmos battery or restarts or memory.

Comment: MemTestx86 reported zero errors on my 8gb of ram.  I had to use the older v4 of memtest as my bios doesn't support UEFI.

Comment: Front power switch is not shorting, PSU voltages to motherboard test okay.  I can start the pc without the cmos battery installed, it takes a while longer to get to the OS, but works.  I'm starting to suspect my motherboard is failing.

Comment: Ugh... I replaced the motherboard with an identical one, and the problem persists...

Comment: After a few restarts (on purpose) and swapping the cmos battery to a known good one (not just whatever shipped with the board) my pc appears to be working.  No more power-up looping after shut down.  So... fixed, I think?